# Starcraft 2 - alternate map types

Tags: starcraft-2

What kind of alternate "games" are there in Starcraft 2? In the same way that WC3 spawned DOTA, what has SC2 spawned so far...?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of successful mods for Starcraft 2? because we're not really a good resource for that kind of information.

Comment: Hmmm....fair point. I guess some of the things that have been tried. I was playing a game of Phantom last night, and just wondered what else there was.

Comment: while this might not be a good venue for that discussion, you can try in [chat](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/rooms/3/general)

Comment: They are sorted by popularity already ingame, so I'm not sure what more you want from us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already almost all the custom maps that were available in previous Blizzard games, though usually a little less advanced and with a SC2 theme instead of a WC3 theme.

There are two or three DotA Versions, a lot of Tower Defense maps, Nexus Wars, Income Wars, some Racing game (

), some First Person shooters, etc.

I don't think there is anything "new" compared to WC3, but SC2 is still quite young

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but where do I donwnload them from?